# error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Ex1'

Tags: typescript

Code:

```
enum Ex0 {
    One = '/home/node/',
    Two = '/home/node/'
}

enum Ex1 {
    One = path.normalize('~/'),
    Two = path.normalize('~/')
}
```

Error:

```
application/libs/config.ts:19:11 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Ex1'.

19     One = path.normalize('~/'),
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

application/libs/config.ts:20:11 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Ex1'.

20     Two = path.normalize('~/')
```

I'm having issues understanding Typescript Enums due to the lack of good documentation. Could anyone explain what i am doing wrong here. `path.normalize` returns a type `string`.

Comment: Are you running Typescript v2.4 by any chance? There was a bug specific to that version that could cause the behavior you're describing. See [this page](https://code-examples.net/en/q/2b19130) for details.